# True flatten a PDF file with PHP, Python or JS

Tags: python, php, pdf

I have several PDF files that have problem rendering and editing.

Usually due to layers and configuration, when this happens I use tools like https://www.sejda.com/pt/flatten-pdf to merge the layers and this solves it.

But I need to implement this in code, but all the content I find is wrong/outdated or uses paid libraries and/or tools.

The idea would be to truly flatten all PDF layers into a single image layer.

Like this:
Prev:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KZng.png)

After:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcFa2.png)

Thank you.

I already tried to do this with python using several libraries, I tried with ghostscripts and in PHP with TCPDF and FPDI

Comment: Yes, the output from Sejda is what we need, but it needs to run on code, maybe with an API, when the user upload the doc to our software we need to merge all the layers.

Comment: Exactly, what I need is to convert all the layers of each page into an image and then export the PDF, in this way I avoid errors in the edition of layers overlapping others and texts with problem in fonts and etc.
But I need to do this in PHP, Python or JS

Comment: This would simply mean to remove the `/OCProperties` from the catalog. That causes all OCGs to be ignored. Then make an image of each page at desired resolution.